# Django form submission

Tags: python, django, forms, django-models, django-forms

I have question about form submission in Django 1.8. The problem is on logic for submission form. When two forms are executed in template, first form save normally to database, but other wont save. I don't know what I'm doing wrong in form submission. Or maybe it's a problem in forms.py. Have look below in my code:

## models.py

```
class IzibiziUser(AbstractEmailUser):

    full_name  = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, db_index=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True)
    last_name  = models.CharField(max_length=35, blank=True)

    role_id         = models.ForeignKey('Roles', null=True, blank=True)
    organization_id = models.ForeignKey('IzibiziOrganization', null=True, blank=True)


    @property
    def __str__(self):
        return self.full_name

class OrganizationInfo(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    oib = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    postal_code = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.EmailField()
    iban = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    webpage = models.URLField()
    delivery_address = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    delivery_city = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    delivery_postal_code = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    delivery_country = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)

class OutgoingInvoice(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    invoice_number = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    time = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    place = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    due_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    total_invoice_amount = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=5, max_digits=255, blank=True, null=True)
    vat_amount = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=5, max_digits=255, blank=True, null=True)
    invoice_amount = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=5, max_digits=255, blank=True, null=True)
    discount = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=5, max_digits=255, blank=True, null=True)
    user_id = models.ForeignKey('IzibiziUser', blank=True, null=True)
    organization_id = models.ForeignKey('IzibiziOrganization', blank=True, null=True)
    customer_id = models.ForeignKey('OrganizationInfo', blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

## forms.py

```
# New Outgoing Invoice
class InsertNewCustomer(forms.ModelForm):
    name        = forms.RegexField(regex=r'\w+',  label=_('Klijent'),widget   = forms.TextInput({'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Klijent'}))
    oib         = forms.RegexField(regex=r'\d.+', label=_('OIB'),widget  = forms.TextInput({'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'OIB'} ))
    address     = forms.RegexField(regex=r'\w+',  label=_('Adresa'), widget  = forms.TextInput({'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Adresa'}))
    city        = forms.RegexField(regex=r'\w+',  label=_('Grad'), widget  = forms.TextInput({'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Grad'}))
    postal_code = forms.RegexField(regex=r'\w+',  label=('Poštanski broj'),widget  = forms.TextInput({'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Poštanski broj'}))


    @property
    def clean_form(self):
        try:
            obj = OrganizationInfo.object.get(oib__iexact=self.cleaned_data['oib'])
        except OrganizationInfo.DoesNotExist:
            return self.clean_form

    class Meta:
        model = OrganizationInfo
        fields = ('name', 'oib', 'address', 'city', 'postal_code',)
        exclude = (
            'country', 'phone', 'email', 'iban', 'webpage', 'delivery_address', 'delivery_city', 'delivery_postal_code',
            'delivery_country', )


class OutNewInovice(forms.ModelForm):


    date            = forms.RegexField(regex=r'\w+', label=('Datum računa'), widget  = forms.TextInput({'class':'form-control date-now', 'placeholder':'Datum računa'}))
    due_date        = forms.DateField(label=('Datum dospjeća'), widget  = forms.TextInput({'class':'form-control select_date', 'placeholder':'Datum dospjeća'}))
    time            = forms.RegexField(regex=r'\w+', label=_('Vrijeme'), widget  = forms.TextInput({'class':'form-control time-now', 'placeholder':'Vrijeme'}))
    status          = forms.ChoiceField(widget = forms.Select({'class':'selectpicker'}),choices = ([('1','Neplaćeno'), ('2','Plaćeno')]), initial='1', required = True, )
    place           = forms.RegexField(regex=r'\w+',  label=_('Mjesto'), widget  = forms.TextInput({'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Mjesto'}))
    invoice_number  = forms.RegexField(regex=r'\w+', label=('Broj računa'), widget  = forms.TextInput({'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Broj računa'}))

    #status.forms.widget.attrs[{'class': 'selectpicker'}]

    class Meta:
        model = OutgoingInvoice

        fields = ('date', 'due_date', 'time', 'status', 'place', 'invoice_number',)
        exclude = ('total_invoice_amount', 'vat_amount', 'vat_amount', 'invoice_amount', 'discount', )
```

## views.py

```
@login_required
@csrf_protect
def NewOutgoingInvoice(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    template = "novi_izlazni_racun.html"

    user_pk = request.user.id
    org_name = OrganizationInfo.objects.filter(id=user_pk).values('name')[0]
    wtf = OrganizationInfo.objects.filter(id=user_pk).values('id')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form1 = InsertNewCustomer(request.POST, prefix='form1')
        form2 = OutNewInovice(request.POST, prefix='form2')
        if all([form1.is_valid(), form2.is_valid()]):
            a = form1.save()
            b = form2.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/novi_izlazni_racuni/')
    else:
        form1 = InsertNewCustomer(prefix='form1')
        form2 = OutNewInovice(prefix='form2')

    variables =  {
        'name': org_name,
        'form1': form1,
        'form2': form2,
    }
    return render(request, template, variables,context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

## Template

```
<form  action="/novi_izlazni_racuni/"  method="POST" role="form" >
    {% csrf_token %}
<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">{{ form1.name.label }} <span class="example1">*</span></label>
                {{ form1.name }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">{{ form1.oib.label }} <span class="example1">*</span></label>
                {{ form1.oib }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 mar-btm">
            <label class="control-label">{{ form1.address.label }} <span class="example1">*</span></label>
            {{ form1.address }}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 mar-btm">
            <label class="control-label">{{ form1.city.label }} <span class="example1">*</span></label>
            {{ form1.city }}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 mar-btm">
            <label class="control-label">{{ form1.postal_code.label }} <span class="example1">*</span></label>
            {{ form1.postal_code }}
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title" style="margin-left: -15px;">DETALJI RAČUNA</h3>
        <div class="row bord-top" style="opacity:1;"></div> <!--Horizontal line-->
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 mar-btm">
            <label class="control-label">{{ form2.date.label }} <span class="example1">*</span></label>
            {{ form2.date }}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 mar-btm">
            <label class="control-label">{{ form2.time.label }} <span class="example1">*</span></label>
            {{ form2.time }}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 mar-btm">
            <label class="control-label">{{ form2.place.label }} <span class="example1">*</span></label>
            {{ form2.place }}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 mar-btm">
            <label class="control-label">{{ form2.due_date.label }} <span class="example1">*</span></label>
            {{ form2.due_date }}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 mar-btm">
            <p style="margin:0 0 5.1px;">{{ form2.status.label }} <span class="example1">*</span></p>
            {{ form2.status }}

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 mar-btm">
            <label class="control-label">{{ form2.invoice_number.label }}</label>
            {{ form2.invoice_number }}
        </div>
    </div>
```

The model OrganizationInfo after new insert where result in database don't exist it work. But insert into OutgoingInvoice won't work, that is a problem. So if you could give me some example on this.

Comment: Can you add the template?

Comment: I have updated my question with html, Klaus D.

Comment: You're sure that the first form is saving? Why are you saving `form.save()` to a variable?

Comment: Yea I'm sure. If not exist in database first form works ok. But second one dont work.